# SPDY module for IIS7

Tags: iis-7, protocols, spdy

My goal is to implement [SPDY protocol](http://dev.chromium.org/spdy) ([a new experimental protocol by GOOGLE](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/spdy/spdy-whitepaper)) on IIS servers.

SPDY is a TCP based application level protocol and as such I am guessing that I have to 
work at TCP level (socket programing) as the built in extensions are for HTTP.

My problem is that once I write a socket programing code to do the same, where do I plug it into IIS7? WAS looks like a good candidate and if so, how do I go about doing it?

Comment: Why would IIS be involved with this protocol?

Comment: Well... MS is working on its own version of a faster internet called S&M (Speed+Mobile): http://www.extremetech.com/computing/124153-sm-vs-spdy-microsoft-and-google-battle-over-the-future-of-http-2-0

Comment: IIS maker's work related with SPDY is distinguished on http://www.extremetech.com/computing/124153-sm-vs-spdy-microsoft-and-google-battle-over-the-future-of-http-2-0 IIS extensibility is through "IIS modules". Once the module is built (MS build chain is available as Windows SDK) and for almost every tool open source alternatives are also available, besides complete cross-compatible chain's commercial alternative by Borland, just plug-in the module onto the target host through web.Config
For up-to-date doc on where to plug-in search for:<br/>IIS modules web.Config

Comment: https://github.com/MSOpenTech/HTTP-SPEED-PLUS-MOBILITY and/or check this link https://github.com/MSOpenTech/http2-katana

Comment: I find it a bit funny that this post was closed as off topic, but literally every site talking about IIS/Windows+SPDY on the internet links here =p

Answer (score 47):

IIS has little or nothing to do with SPDY. IIS is just an application server that responds to HTTP requests handed off by the `http.sys` kernel mode driver. All HTTP requests in Windows are handled by this driver.

This is the level at which SPDY would be need to be implemented.

If you were to implement SPDY you'd need to have this as a shim driver between the TCP stack and `http.sys`, or maybe even write your own `http.sys` driver.

Alternatively you could write your own SPDY/HTTP stack but if you wanted to use this with IIS then you're in for a lot of work.

Comment: `IIS has little or nothing to do with SPDY` How would the web server  know to serve assets with SPDY? In my head, I would see it as being a configurable setting in IIS.

Comment: @Jeff - absolutely true - if SPDY was built into IIS. But given that OP is trying to implement this from scratch because presently there is no support at all he's on a bit of a hiding to nothing. That is my point.

Comment: Please mark as answer if the question was answered.

Comment: @Kosau - I wouldn't hold out much hope, I think the user who asked this question has long since left the site (last seen: Jun 3 '11). :)

Comment: Or the OP can use Apache/mod_spdy as a proxy to IIS. SPDY is designed to overcome latency/concurrency problems that localhost connections (routed in-memory) don't show